# How does `bquote` handle the dimensions of terms wrapped in `.()`?

Tags: r, quote

I am confused about how `bquote` handles multidimensional terms (e.g., a matrix)
wrapped in `.()`.

Suppose I have the following `X` matrix.

```r
# Set a seed exact draws.
set.seed(2023)

# Create a matrix.
X <- matrix(sample(1:100, 9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
X
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   80   26   29
# [2,]   47   44   49
# [3,]   72   65   81
```

Wrapping `X` in `.()` does what I expect, i.e., it retains its dimensions.

```r
# Wrap `X` in `.()`.
bquote(.(X))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]   80   26   29
# [2,]   47   44   49
# [3,]   72   65   81
```

However, in the context of a function call, it seems that `X` is coerced to a
vector. Despite this, `R` somehow still knows that `X` is a matrix, as seen in the output of the `apply` call below.

```r
# Apply a function over rows.
output <- apply(X = X, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) mean(row))
output
# [1] 45.00000 46.66667 72.66667

# Create an expression to apply a function over rows later.
expr <- bquote(apply(X = .(X), MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) mean(row)))
expr
# apply(X = c(80L, 47L, 72L, 26L, 44L, 65L, 29L, 49L, 81L), MARGIN = 1,
#    FUN = function(row) mean(row))

# Not necessary, but remove `X`.
rm(X, envir = .GlobalEnv)

# Evaluate the expression and compare it with the previous output.
eval(expr) == output
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

How does `R` know that `X` is a matrix in the `expr` expression above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bquote` is irrelevant here.  A simpler example:

```r
> expr <- call("is.matrix", matrix(1:4, 2L, 2L))
> expr[[2L]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4

> eval(expr)
# [1] TRUE

> print(expr)
# is.matrix(1:4)
```

The argument of the call *is* a matrix, but `print.default` deparses it without attributes. `deparse` does the right thing:

```r
> writeLines(deparse(expr))
# is.matrix(structure(1:4, dim = c(2L, 2L)))
```

The reason is that `deparse` uses the `"showAttributes"` option by default:

```r
> (ctrl <- eval(formals(deparse)[["control"]]))
# [1] "keepNA"         "keepInteger"    "niceNames"   "showAttributes"
```

This character vector is converted by `.deparseOpts` to an integer whose *bits* indicate whether the respective options are turned on or off:

```r
> .deparseOpts(ctrl)
# [1] 1093
```

The header file [`Defn.h`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-3-branch/src/include/Defn.h) in R's sources defines the mapping:

```c
/* deparse option bits: change do_dump if more are added */

#define KEEPINTEGER         1
#define QUOTEEXPRESSIONS    2
#define SHOWATTRIBUTES      4
#define USESOURCE           8
#define WARNINCOMPLETE      16
#define DELAYPROMISES       32
#define KEEPNA              64
#define S_COMPAT            128
#define HEXNUMERIC          256
#define DIGITS17            512
#define NICE_NAMES          1024
/* common combinations of the above */
#define SIMPLEDEPARSE       0
#define DEFAULTDEPARSE      1089 /* KEEPINTEGER | KEEPNA | NICE_NAMES, used for calls */
#define FORSOURCING         95 /* not DELAYPROMISES, used in edit.c */
```

If you dig around in [`print.c`](https://svn.r-project.org/R/branches/R-4-3-branch/src/main/print.c), then you'll find (in the body of function `PrintLanguage`) that `print.default` uses the `DEFAULTDEPARSE` option for language objects.  It has the `SHOWATTRIBUTES` bit turned off, and there is no option for the user to turn it on.

Well, I've just asked in the R-devel mailing list (i.e., see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2023-May/082608.html)) if `DEFAULTDEPARSE` should be changed to 1093 to match the R level default.

Comment: Indeed, I expected to see a `structure` call with the corresponding dimensions. Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Can you please add the link to the `R-devel` thread where you asked about the change of `DEFAULTDEPARSE` to your answer? Thanks for elucidating this!

Comment: I added the link.